# Human biology - liver regeneration after laprascopic segmentectomy

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, liver, surgery

I am trying to understand to what extent human patients can regenerate liver mass after laprascopic segmentectomy: what part of liver will be regenerated and how fully.

My work with sources is not very good, but here is what I have found so far:

[Michalopoulos, G. K., & DeFrances, M. (2005). Liver regeneration. Advances in biochemical engineering/biotechnology, 93, 101–134.](https://doi.org/10.1007/b99968):

*"Following surgical resection of the two anterior hepatic lobes of rodents accounting for ~68% of liver tissue, the remaining lobes undergo compensatory hyperplasia restoring the liver to its original presurgical mass"*
[image]
However, the article notes that:

*"..PHx model doesn't apply to most common clinical scenarios.. patients who must regenerate liver mass after hepatic surgery often have cirrhosis, hepatic viral infection, steatosis.."*

From this question ([If the liver can regenerate why can alcohol abuse permanently damage it?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/48951/if-the-liver-can-regenerate-why-can-alcohol-abuse-permanently-damage-it)) I gathered that only healthy hepatic tissue in liver can regenerate: the epithelial tissue.
Cytotoxic drugs like alcohol lead to steatosis and cirrhosis. Cirrhosis is the substitution of epithelial tissue by connective tissue. This connective tissue not only can't regenerate: it doesn't perform hepatic functions.

Assuming that the patient has otherwise healthy liver tissue, if a laprascopic resection of liver segment Sg3 has been performed, what part of the liver will be regenerated?

[image]

Thank you in advance, and I would be happy to edit/update my question with more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The healthy human liver has remarkable ability to regenerate in only a few months after resection.

In a study of 98 healthy donors who underwent left lobectomy donation, Chen and colleagues found that donors started with a mean liver volume of 1154 cm³, had an average of 276 cm³ removed, and then had an average liver volume of 1065 cm³ 6 months later (2006. PMID [17100722](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17100722/)). Thus, on average, 68% of the donated liver volume had regenerated in those 6 months.

In my research, I was unable to find a systematic study of the location or direction of regeneration. Although hyperplasia appears to be the mechanism of regeneration (Marongiu *et al* 2017. PMCID [5352916](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5352916/)), intuitively, we should suspect that the remaining liver will increase in volume rather than the removed lobe suddenly re-spouting somehow like a salamander's tail.

This set of 3 CT scans from a study by Esschert and colleagues provides anecdotal evidence for this intuition (2009. PMCID [2710489](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2710489/)):

[image: 3 CT images of liver volumes]
<sup>Figure 1 from Esschert *et al* 2009 showing post-operative liver regeneration after 3 months, available [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2710489/).</sup>

In addition to the return of liver volume, donors also have no evidence of decreased liver function at least as long as 5 years post-operatively (Murad *et al* 2016. [27144969](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27144969/)).

The above studies do not appear to delineate whether surgeries were performed open or laparoscopically, but I suspect that any effect of the less invasive laparoscopic procedure would only improve regeneration.

As an interesting aside, even after performing as many as 4 separate resections for patients with recurring hepatocellular carcinoma, Yamaguchi and colleagues found continued high rates of liver regeneration (over 90%) (Yamaguchi *et al* 2018. PMID [29947985](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29947985/)).

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer, Ian! Great first post!